# JavaScript function is called before clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SLEX/) code. What I am is I have an `Cal` object which consists of `init` function and another object called `Event`. Inside `Event` I have two functions `init` and `show`. What I am doing is calls `init` function of `Cal` object and passing parameter in there. Inside this `init` function I am calling `Event`'s `init` function and passing that same parameter here. and inside this `init` function I am calling `show` function inside `Event` when user clicks on `.button` link which shows `param` in the console. But when I run this code, it shows `param` in the console before clicking `.button`. **Why and how can I make it work so that it shows param when I click on .button?**

Here is my code

```
var Cal = {
    init: function (param) {
        this.param = param;
        Cal.Event.init(this.param);
    },

    func: function () {},

    Event: {
        init: function (param) {
            $('.button').on('click', this.show(param));
        },

        show: function (param) {
            console.log(param);
        }
    }
}

Cal.init('para');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
init: function (param) {
    $('.button').on('click', this.show(param));
},
```

You're **calling** the `show` function and then passing its return value into `on`, so it runs when you call `Cal.Event.init`. You're not giving `on` code to call when the click occurs. To do that, put it in an event handler function:

```
init: function (param) {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        Cal.Event.show(param);
    });
},
```

Note that I changed `this` to `Cal.Event` because within the call to the handler function, `this` will be a reference to the button, not `Cal.Event`.

Answer (score 4):

.on() expect parameter 2 to be a function, not the return value of that function

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    // Here this points to the button DOM object.
    Cal.Event.show(param)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You call `this.show(param)` immediately. Change it to this:

```
init: function (param) {
    $('.button').on('click', $.proxy(function() {
        this.show(param);
    }, this));
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9SLEX/3/

Comment: why use `$.proxy()` in this example?

Comment: @x4ph4r To preserve context so inside click handler `this` will point to `Cal.Event` object. If you want context to be `.button` then you should use what Virus721 suggests.